# Different number of bounding boxes per image, tried padding, but boxes with zeros are invalid for training object detection model

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, padding, collate

I am training a faster r cnn for object detection, or at least trying to. I have an annotated dataset with bounding boxes and labels, however each image has a different number of bounding boxes as each image has a different number of objects. I got an error " stack expects each tensor to be equal size but got [16] at entry 0 and [15] at entry 1 " so I made sure each image had the same number of bounding boxes by using padding. For this I used:

```
def collate_fn(batch):
    images = []
    labels_list = []
    bboxes_list = []

    for image, labels, bboxes in batch:
        images.append(image)

        labels = torch.tensor(labels, dtype=torch.long)
        bboxes = torch.tensor(bboxes, dtype=torch.float)

        labels_list.append(labels)
        bboxes_list.append(bboxes)

    # Pad the bounding boxes to have a fixed number of bounding boxes per image
    max_num_bboxes = max(bbox.size(0) for bbox in bboxes_list)
    padded_bboxes = []
    padded_labels = []
    for bbox, label in zip(bboxes_list, labels_list):
        num_bboxes = bbox.size(0)
        pad_size = max_num_bboxes - num_bboxes
        if pad_size > 0:
            padding_bbox = torch.zeros(pad_size, 4)   
            padding_label = torch.zeros(pad_size, dtype=torch.long)  # Background label for padded boxes
            bbox = torch.cat((bbox, padding_bbox), dim=0)
            label = torch.cat((label, padding_label), dim=0)
        padded_bboxes.append(bbox)
        padded_labels.append(label)

    return torch.stack(images), (torch.stack(padded_labels), torch.stack(padded_bboxes))
```

However, now I get the error: "all bounding boxes should have positive height and width. Found invalid box [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

I tried padding to make the number of bounding boxes equal